# Passing an array of arguments to apply in Typescript

Tags: typescript, apply

Solution:

```
private compiledFn: Maybe<(data: any) => void> = null;
```

I just want to pass my array of arguments using `apply`

```
// function... I can see there is a problem here
private compiledFn: Maybe<() => void> = null;

// calling with apply
let arg = [data];
return this.compiledFn.apply(data, arg);
```

But get this error:

```
semantic error TS2345 Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'.
Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'.
```

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? Can you share signature of the function on which apply is called?

Comment: @MasterChief Updated. I think I get why now but what should the signature be?